# Solve $\int \frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{e^x}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How should I calculate this integral$$\int\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{e^x}dx~~~~?$$
I don't know what is the first step, so I tried symbolab calculator but this cannot solve.
Can someone help me to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: apply linearity and rewrite $1/e^x=e^{-x}$.

Comment: Decompose as $\int \sin(x) e^{-x} dx + \int \cos(x) e^{-x} dx$ and integrate by parts in the first integral.

Comment: @csch2 This hint helped me to solve. Thanks

Comment: wolframalpha.com calculates it just fine. Perhaps you can consider using it as a reference.

Comment: You could use Euler's formula. $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral can be re-written as $$I=\sqrt{2}\int e^{-x} \sin (x+\pi/4)~ dx.$$ You may do it by parts, two times. Second time $I$ will re-appear, take it LHS to get the final result.

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{d(e^{-x}(a\cos x+b\sin x)}{dx}$$

$$=e^{-x}(-a\sin x+b\cos x-a\cos x-b\sin x)$$

Compare the coefficients of $e^{-x}\cos x,e^{-x}\sin x$ with $$e^{-x}(\cos x+\sin x)$$ to find

$b-a=1,-a-b=1,a=?,b=?$

Answer (score 1):

Note the integral fornula:
$$\int e^{-x}(f(x)-f'(x)) dx=-e^{-x} f(x).$$
So here $$\int e^{-x} (\cos x+\sin x) dx=-e^{-x} \cos x +C$$